# Crash on ios cocos2d-x swap buffers

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

Our crash report software reports the following crash, with main line `[CCEAGLView swapBuffers]`. Does anyone have any idea what might went wrong, what is causing it and  how to fix it? It happens very randomly.

```
Crashed Thread
0   
libGPUSupportMercury.dylib 0x000000018f209f08 gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient + 8
1   
GLEngine 0x0000000187fa31e4 gliPresentViewES_Exec + 172
2   
GLEngine 0x0000000187fa30fc gliPresentViewES + 80
3   
OpenGLES 0x0000000187fafcbc -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] + 68
4   
**AppName iOS 0x0000000100502554 -[CCEAGLView swapBuffers] + 292
5** 
AppName iOS 0x000000010047b364 _ZN7cocos2d8Director9drawSceneEv + 324
6   
AppName iOS 0x000000010047c7b0 _ZN7cocos2d19DisplayLinkDirector8mainLoopEv + 64
7   
QuartzCore 0x0000000189843840 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 36
8   
QuartzCore 0x00000001898436f4 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items() + 420
9   
IOKit 0x0000000185d022f8 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 368
10  
CoreFoundation 0x0000000184a0a840 __CFMachPortPerform + 176
11  
CoreFoundation 0x0000000184a20c7c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
12  
CoreFoundation 0x0000000184a203b4 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 432
13  
CoreFoundation 0x0000000184a1e10c __CFRunLoopRun + 1796
14  
CoreFoundation 0x000000018494cca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380
15  
GraphicsServices 0x000000018fb88088 GSEventRunModal + 176
16  
UIKit 0x000000018a064ffc UIApplicationMain + 200
17  
AppName iOS 0x00000001002aaf3c main + 80
18  
libdyld.dylib 0x0000000199e6a8b8 start + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you show another view you must first use `Director::stopAnimation`, and then `Director::startAnimation` when you discard the `UIView`.